# Which of these BDD tools are more appropriate and has more advantages for C# applications?

Tags: c#-4.0, bdd

I would like to know your recommendation for which tool has more advantages when it comes to  BDD development process:

- SpecFlow
- Cuke4Nuke (Cucumber port for
  .NET)
- Nbehave
- StoreEvil
- [Bddify](https://code.google.com/p/bddify/)
- [NSpec](http://nspec.org)
- Nspecify
- StoryQ

I personally use Cucumber (on Ruby for Windows), also it seems SpecFlow is very similar.
But I would like your recommendation on any other nice tools!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add [MSpec](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications) to your list. MSpec is my personal favourite simply because I've used it more often/regularly. Which one you chose is, as with Unit Testing frameworks, mainly an primarily a matter of taste.

Take a couple of them out for a test run and decide based on:

- Which one you feel the most comfortable with
- Which has the better (online) documentation
- Which has the liveliest community

Answer (score 0):

You've missed out my recommendation:

Write it in code.

It's not very hard to knock up a little DSL which can support your BDD. [Here's one I made earlier.](http://code.google.com/p/wipflash/source/browse/Example.PetShop.Scenarios/PetRegistrationAndPurchase.cs) Even business people can read this.

The only reason to use BDD frameworks, really, is to capture the conversations you have with your business stakeholders. The conversations are [much more important](http://lizkeogh.com/2011/03/04/step-away-from-the-tools/)! If your business stakeholders aren't reading or writing the scenarios themselves then all you do with a BDD framework is introduce another layer of indirection. (I helped write JBehave and still prefer code.)

Having said that, if you feel you get benefit from a BDD framework, I hear great things about SpecFlow.